# my quiz count down timer not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have created simple quiz site in php i wanted to integrate countdown timer of 30 seconds for each question here is the code:

```
var timeleft = 30;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    }
    document.getElementById("quiz").submit();
},1000);
```

timer code:

```
You have  <span id='countdowntimer'> </span> Seconds left
```

The problem is when quiz starts the form is submitted before timer ends I want the form submitted after timer reaches to 0 .

all right yovopaw solved my problem but now there is one more, the code for quiz:

```
<form action="process.php" method="get" id="quiz">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="questions">
                                <li> <h3><?php echo $question['questions']; ?></h3> 
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">  
                                        <?php
                                            while($choice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                         echo "<li><input type='radio' name='quiz' class='choices' value='".$choice['id']."' > ".$choice['choices']."  </li> ";
                                        } ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <input type="hidden" name="start" value=<?php echo $start; ?>>
                                <input type="hidden" name="cate" value=<?php echo $selected; ?>>
                                <input type="hidden" name="total" value=<?php echo $total; ?>>
                                <input type="hidden" name="qn" value=<?php echo $questionnumber; ?>>
                                <li> <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" id="next"> </li> 
                            </ul>
                        </form>
```

also here is javascript code for stopping use to go to next question if no choice is selected

```
document.getElementById("quiz").onsubmit = function(event){
            var btn = document.getElementById("next");

    var choices = document.getElementsByClassName("choices");
    for(var i=0;i<choices.length;i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            return true;
        }
    }
        event.preventDefault();
        return alert("you must choose option first");
    }
```

so the problem is when user click on choice and click next it works as expected but when timer reaches to 0 and form is submitted it does not go to next question i just get blank page with url populated with those hidden fields values .

Comment: Is it just before it hits zero you see this? Can you try moving `timeleft--` down under `if (timeleft <= 0)  { ... }` `//here`, outside the braces

Comment: no the moment quiz starts the form is submitted it never count down

Comment: Move the `submit()` call inside the `if` condition

Comment: It's because the form submit statement is not within the if block.

Comment: You can try countdown.js, http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var timeleft = 30;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
  timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        console.log(`SUBMIT`)
    }},1000);
```

```html
You have  <span id='countdowntimer'> </span> Seconds left
```

Comment: seems like a good answer, moving the submit inside the time left check, I've upvoted. Maybe add some more explanation, but seems clear enough to me.

Comment: But as suggested @David, you should add more details about how you fixed it.

Comment: you are right yovopaw thanks for your effert . but i edited my question there is one more problem